# Move text in UITextField with animation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I need to move `text` in `UITextField` (from right to left, and then back) with animation like in *Safari App in iOS 7* (see the screenshots below).
Is there any way to do it?
I know that I can set `textAlignment`, but it won't be animated.

Maybe I should change `leftView` size in `UITextField`? But I'm not sure how to calculate size, when text should be aligned on the center. Please, help.~

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [cs424818.vk.me](http://cs424818.vk.me/v424818291/70fa/y7JW2_RKPnA.jpg))</sub>

Comment: If i would venture a guess I would say its a sub class of UITextField with a lot of behavior (code) built around it that's not available with regular UITextField

Comment: that is a simple transition effect (moving + fading) between a `UITextField` and a `UILabel`. that is quite primitive concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior by doing this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // add this to viewDidLoad
    // keep the alignment left justified
    [self.yourTextField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    [self.yourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

-(void)textFieldDidChange
{
    // this will cause your textfield to grow and shrink as text is added or removed
    // note: this will always grow to the right, the lefthand side will stay anchored
    [self.yourTextField sizeToFit];
}
```

Then when you want to move your UITextField from the center to the left you can simply do:

```
// 1 second animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    // move to the left side of some containing view
    self.yourTextField.center = CGPointMake(containingView.frame.origin.x + self.yourTextField.frame.size.width/2, self.yourTextField.center.y);
}];
```

Likewise to move from the lefthand side to the center you can do:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    // move to the center of containing view
    self.yourTextField.center = CGPointMake(containingView.frame.size.width/2, self.yourTextField.center.y);
}];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have the urge to put self.yourTextField instead of your_textfield the viewDidLoad and textFieldDidChange (ex. [self.yourTextField sizeToFit]). Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I have a question: how to be, when text width in `UITextField` more, than view size? So if I use `sizeToFit`, `UITextfield` becomes beyond the view. @MikeSlutsky

Comment: You should try using this: [Growing Text View](https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView)

Comment: But why? I don't see any text moving from center to side/from side to center. @nlee918

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want the UITextField to be a specific width, and allow the text to overflow? (sizeToFit does indeed completely make the textField bigger to fit all the text)

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you trying to clone the URL bar from the safari app itself?

Comment: Yes, actually i was trying to do it and finally did. @nlee918
Answer of Mike Slutsky has the same construction as my code, so I mark this answer as accepted answer.
Thanks everybody!